# R add column to match another dataframe

Tags: r, match, addition

I would like to add columns to a main table x to match its columns to dataframe y. Any nice solution can recommend?

```
x=data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3)
y=data.frame(c=NA,b=NA, a=NA)
```

and I want x to be `x=data.frame(c=NA, b=1:3, a=1:3)` so that x table has the same columns in the same orders as y.

thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `merge` and reorder columns afterwards

```
merge(x, y, by = c("a", "b"), all.x = TRUE)[names(y)]
#   c b a
#1 NA 1 1
#2 NA 2 2
#3 NA 3 3
```